# breed-here equivalent for agentsets?

Tags: netlogo

I want to make an agentset of patches that have turtles only of a specific agentset.  This is easy with breeds but is not working for me with an agentset.

All my turtles are the same breed.

```
let moveAgents n-of (count turtles * 0.1) turtles
let availablePlots patches with [any? moveAgents-here]  ;does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invert the search:

```
let availablePlots patch-set [patch-here] of moveAgents
```

Comment: Yes that's it!  Thanks